# How can I access static method from instance type?

Tags: typescript

Below I have a class "YouCantAccessStaticTypeFromInstance" and I am curious if there's a opposite to `InstanceType` that would allow me to access `typeof YouCantAccessStaticTypeFromInstance` the class type from the instance type `YouCantAccessStaticTypeFromInstance`.

```
class YouCantAccessStaticTypeFromInstance {
    static example: boolean
}

type exampleInstance = YouCantAccessStaticTypeFromInstance
 
type x = exampleInstance['example'] // doesn't work
```

Comment: I think you just need to change it to: `type exampleInstance = typeof YouCantAccessStaticTypeFromInstance`

Comment: Looks like @zecuria's [idea works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECaD2BXAwmAdgFwILGAUygGUMwMBLYAFQE8AHPAMQCd4BbASTQhLX2gG8AsAChoY6N1IVoeAB5hWtEHgBc0AEbx4y9CIC+IkRjp4Z8xcs6TepgLzRj9eADM4SVJhz4iJclRPMbFY8+CLQRibQstD2cgpKeMHo+ADaAORxFnhpALrQAPT50AAm8ARoaRjQAO7wTADWQA)

Comment: This answer kind of misses my point, I know typeof class will return the classes type not the instance but I'm trying to work within generics in-scenarios where I only have the instance type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a type from a class doesn't give the new type the ability to hold static methods. A static method is a feature of classes - not types. However, you can make a reference to the class and use the static methods of the class through the reference.

```
let exampleRef = YouCantAccessStaticTypeFromInstance
 
exampleref['example']
```